# How to write blocks (closures) in swift3 right way?

Tags: ios, swift3, pocket

I am trying to find how I can write this blocks in swift3, any help would be appreciated.

I am using obj-c PocketSDK in swift3 project.
https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK

I can use this SDK fine with proper Bridge-Header settings, but still not sure how I can write blocks part.

obj-c

```
[[PocketAPI sharedAPI] callAPIMethod:@"get"
                       withHTTPMethod:PocketAPIHTTPMethodGET
                            arguments:arguments
                              handler:^(PocketAPI *api, NSString *apiMethod, NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
                              }];
```

This is the type def in PocketSDK.

```
-(void)callAPIMethod:(NSString *)apiMethod withHTTPMethod:(PocketAPIHTTPMethod)HTTPMethod arguments:(NSDictionary *)arguments delegate:(id<PocketAPIDelegate>)delegate;

     typedef void(^PocketAPIResponseHandler)(PocketAPI *api, NSString*apiMethod, NSDictionary *response, NSError *error);
```

swift? (This shows error.)

```
    let arguments: [String: Any] = [
        "state": "unread",
        "count": 20
    ]

    PocketAPI.shared().callMethod("get", with: PocketAPIHTTPMethodGET, arguments: arguments) {
        (api: PocketAPI,
        apiMethod: String,
        esponse: [AnyHashable:Any],
        error: Error) in
    }
```

**@Updated**

I could avoid the compile error without type def, but still get the unrecognized selector if I put arguments. If I set nil in arguments, I don't get it though.  Anything wrong with the dictionary?

```
    var arguments = [String : Any]()
    arguments["count"] = 20
    arguments["state"] = "unread"

    PocketAPI.shared().callMethod("get", with: PocketAPIHTTPMethodGET, arguments: arguments) {
        (api,
        apiMethod,
        response,
        error) in
    }
```

Error.

> -[_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174624540 2017-08-15 14:05:51.345611+0900
>   Voicepaper2[1062:286998] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber
>   length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174624540'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Comment: I think in swift you dont have to declare type when call it, just need the variables name

Comment: Thanks, it seems like arguments part (How to make Dictionary in swift) could be wrong.

Comment: I updated the question, it would be appreciated if you could take a look when you have time.

Comment: Have you tried using NSDictionary instead of [String: Any]? They're not the same thing.

Comment: The problem was "count": 20, but it should be "20".  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  This was the final answer, thanks!

```
    let arguments: [String: Any] = [
        "state": "unread",
        "count": "20"
    ]

    PocketAPI.shared().callMethod("get", with: PocketAPIHTTPMethodGET, arguments: arguments) {
        (api,
        apiMethod,
        response,
        error) in
    }
```